# Vue.js: dev works but build+preview fails

Tags: vue.js, vite

I have a Vite + Vue.js 3 poryect in typescript and when I do `npm run dev` and enter in http://localhost:5173/ everithing works, but when I do `npm run build && npm run preview` and enter in http://localhost:4173/ the web give me a this javascript error `TypeError: d.events is undefined`, which is impossible to debug because of all code have been minimized.

I though that is something works in dev, it should be work in build + preview.

1. Am I missing something or skipping some mandatory step?
2. How can I build my project whiteout minimized?

UPDATE: I have this method in a store:

```js
storemap.$subscribe((mutation, state) => {
  if (map == null) return;
  if (
    mutation.events.key != "layer" ||
    mutation.events.newValue == mutation.events.oldValue
  )
    return;
  console.log("storemap.layer", storemap.layer);
  map.addSelectedLayer(state.layer);
});
```

I have added in the second `if` this condition `mutation.events == null ||` and `TypeError: d.events is undefined` disappeared (although the web is still not working).

It is very difficult debug in this way. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1):

Events is only available in dev: https://pinia.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/pinia.SubscriptionCallbackMutationPatchObject.html#events